# Get nodes by USER_ID (query)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have orders. Each order has items.

Each order and each item are assigned by an user.

Below is the my list of items of each order:

[image]

Is it possible to get a list of all nodes assigned by `USER_1_ID?` Or I have to change my structure?

in this case: a query which returns node numbers `15` and `1`

Comment: Update your question with your programming language tag

Comment: Sorry for this. I was sure it's the same for all with the using firebase queries. I'm using Angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to filter data:

```
var root = firebase.database().ref();
var query = root.child("order_items").orderByChild("user").equalTo("USER_1_ID");
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to get the items in one go, you can listen for the `value` event and iterate over the children in the snapshot you get there:

```
query.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key);
  });
});
```

I recommend you read the Firebase documentation, specifically the [section on filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

Comment: I'm not sure you noticed - In your code, your using `.orderByChild("user")` on the 2nd node, while the node with the `user` is the 3rd level one. Will your code work and return the result of items within every order, or only for specific one?

Comment: Sorry it was just me, Thanks!